# How can I add search paths outside CMAKE_SYSROOT for cmake's find_path?

Tags: cmake

I'm using a cmake toolchain file with the following:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSROOT /path/to/toolchain/system/libraries)

# These are to make cmake use the toolchain and not accidentally use my system's includes/libraries
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)
```

I would like to add a separate include path outside CMAKE_SYSROOT:

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_PATH /absolute/path/to/include)
```

But `find_path` simply doesn't work. Thankfully I can debug it by passing `-DCMAKE_FIND_DEBUG_MODE=ON` to cmake:

```
  find_path considered the following locations:

  /path/to/toolchain/system/libraries/absolute/path/to/include

  The item was not found.
```

Well there's the problem CMAKE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_PATH is relative to CMAKE_SYSROOT (which is not stated in the [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_PATH.html#variable:CMAKE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_PATH)). What are my options? Is there another variable I can set to add an absolute search path to [`find_path`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/command/find_path.html#command:find_path)?

`CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` can give an absolute path but cmake appends extra paths to it that I don't want, such as `usr`/`bin`/`include` and not just the straight path. Relative paths with `../` seem to be filtered out too.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this abomination which seems to work. I would suggest not doing this at all costs as it chekcs waaay more paths than the one you want...

```
# In the cross compile toolchain file.
# This is so find_path can find things in ABSOLUTE_INCLUDE_PATHS.
foreach(PATH ${ABSOLUTE_INCLUDE_PATHS})
get_filename_component(PARENT ${PATH} DIRECTORY)
get_filename_component(LASTPART ${PATH} NAME)
list(APPEND CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${PARENT})
list(APPEND CMAKE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_PATH /${LASTPART})
endforeach()
```

This works because `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` supports adding multiple absolute paths outside `CMAKE_SYSROOT`. However it also adds a tonne of path suffixes, without checking the path itself. The solution is to add the parent directory as the root and then the `LASTPART` as one of the many combinations searched under the root. Note the `/`. This will proceed to search `LASTPART` in all the other roots too.